# How to get only video files from folder directory of all files in php?

Tags: php, scandir

I have some videos,images and text files in "uploads/video/" dir.
Here i am getting all the files using `scandir` but I want only videos from that folder.

Sample code :

```
$video_dir    = 'uploads/video/';
$video_array = scandir($video_dir);

unset($video_array[0]);
unset($video_array[1]);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($video_array);
echo "</pre>";
```

Getting Result :

```
Array ( [2] => ADD.mp4 [3] => COO_Notes.txt [4] => Carefree.mp3 [5] => Circus Tent.mp3 [6] => Phen.mp4 [7] => REM.mp4 [8] => images (9).jpg [9] => images.jpg [10] => test.php )
```

I need only video files. Remove the text,mp3,jpg,etc files:

```
Array ( [2] => ADD.mp4  [6] => Phen.mp4 [7] => REM.mp4)
```

Thanks for your updates.

Comment: you look at the filenames and decide if the extension is video-related. so, [foreach](http://php.net/foreach), [pathinfo](http://php.net/pathinfo), and/or probably [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter)

Comment: Means i need to check every file is video format or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `glob()`:

```
<?php
foreach (glob("*.mp4") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename - Size: " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
}
# or:
$video_array = glob("*.mp4");
?>
```

In order to get multiple formats, simply put the extensions in curly braces and add the parameter `GLOB_BRACE`:

```
$video_array = glob('uploads/video/{*.mp4,*.flv,*.mov}', GLOB_BRACE);
```

See it on [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) here.

Comment: It's working fine for only .mp4 video format. I want to get all videos like mov,flv,etc

Comment: @RamaLingam: Glad to be of any help :-)

Comment: Can i get videos only without specifying *.mp4,*.flv,*.mov ? Is it possible? Suppose i add .avi format video then  i will not get the .avi video.

Comment: @RamaLingam: What do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the function `pathinfo` should help you out.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

```
<?php
$videos = array();
$video_ext = array('mp4', 'mpeg');
foreach ($video_array as $path) {
  if (in_array(pathinfo($path,  PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $video_ext)) {
  //less general, but will work if you know videos always end in mp4
  //if (pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == "mp4") {
    $videos[] = $path;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's working fine. But without $video_ext  is possible?

Comment: yeah, just change `in_array(....)` to `pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == "mp4"`

Answer (score 2):

You may check file type with `mime_content_type`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php.

Assume this will be something like:

```
$videos = array();
$dir = 'uploads';
$files = scandir($dir);
foreach($files as $file) {
   $filepath = $dir . '/' . $file;
   if(is_file($filepath)) {
       $contentType = mime_content_type($filepath);
       if(stripos($contentType, 'video') !== false) {
           $videos[] = $file;
       }
   }
}
```

Also this may be not very fast and perhaps will not detect all possible (strange) video files (as it uses `magic.mime`). But this may work without array of file extensions and also will look at file itself rather than filename.